# Slow query for MySQL using "IN"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

For a large table (1 million records) I have an update query like this:

```
update direct_words set weight = (weight / 4) where knowledge_id = :a 
and phrase_id in (select phrase_id from phrases where knowledge_id =:b 
and phrase_class <> 6);
```

I have several indexes, but one is for the fields:

```
knowledge_id;phrase_id
```

This runs very fast under SQLite (2 seconds or less), but for MySQL the same query takes about 37 seconds. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Learn to use `JOIN` and `EXPLAIN`. (The former because it fits RA concepts well and you don't have to rely on the query planner to unravel it and the latter because it will generally indicate which parts of a plan are most costly.)

Comment: Perhaps an index for `knowledge_id, weight` for the `direct_words` table might help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try execututing it using `JOIN`

```
update  direct_words a
        INNER JOIN phrases b
            ON a.phrase_id = b.phrase_id
set     a.weight = (a.weight / 4) 
where   a.knowledge_id = :a AND
        b.knowledge_id = :b AND
        b.phrase_class <> 6
```

Comment: @bonCodigo not really. `:D`